# "often requires" vs. "may require"

Tags: verbs

1) Starting a business often requires significant financial sacrifices.
2) Starting a business may require significant financial sacrifices.

These have nearly identical meanings. Why is "requires" used in sentence one, whereas "require" is used in sentence two"?

Comment: Because *often* is an adverb and *require* is the tensed verb.  In the second *may* is an auxiliary verb and takes the tense.

Comment: Because of "may." Put "may" in sentence 1 and it will also drop the "s" on "requires": "Starting a business may often require significant financial sacrifices."

Answer (score -1):

**Often requires** implies extensive experience or case studies of the situation described; it's a description of practical knowledge. It also implies that the situation is more common than not.

**May require** does not have the implication of experience, but could be purely theoretical. It's a more passive phrasing, and does not imply the frequency of this outcome at all.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, though